# showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection

Tags: android, emulation

This is a strange error to me, because it only occurs when I switch from portrait to landscape on my emulator; SDK level 17 Android 4.2.2

My widget launches fine on portrait when clicked, but switching to landscape by hitting '7' on my numPad and clicking the widget, will open the MainActivity the first time, but then on subsequent clicks, the widget stops opening the MainActivity...and stops functioning altogether.

Other icons on my homescreen will open fine.

Basically want to understand what showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection means? and why is  it only happening when I switch my emulator to Landscape mode?

Thanks in advance.

My logcat:

```
04-21 19:56:28.956: D/gralloc_goldfish(5826): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
04-21 19:56:41.727: I/Choreographer(5826): Skipped 59 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-21 19:56:41.947: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(5826): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
04-21 19:56:42.607: I/Choreographer(5826): Skipped 62 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```